# HTML justify text-align with <pre> tag

Tags: html, fixed-width, pre, text-justify

I have a problem with the text-align "justify" inside a paragraph with format and fixed width, because I want the paragraph text in HTML to appear totally justified (like it would happen with a MS Word file). However, this does not happen. What I need to modify to achieve it?

```
     <pre style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: medium; width: 500px; text-align: justify;"> 

I have a problem with the text-align "justify" inside a paragraph with format and fixed width, because I want the paragraph text in HTML to appear totally justified (like it would happen with a MS Word file). However, this does not happen. What I need to modify to achieve it?

        </pre>
```

**EDIT:** if I replace the `<pre>` tag with `<p>` tag, my code works properly. Can somebody explain me why? Perhaps I am using a wrong use of `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To justify text in `<pre>` you need to add `white-space: normal;` in your styles, but in my opinion this misses the point using the `<pre>` tag.

-- Edit --

Instead of `<pre>` tag you can just use `<div>` with appropriate styles. It can imitate `<pre>` tag very well and is easier to play with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it but it does not work.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `<pre>` element?

Comment: ^ Good point, @jfpeji you can use `<div>` with appropriate styles. It can imitate `<pre>` very well.

Comment: @MrLister: Thank you for your comment. I realize that I really need the `<p>` tag instead of the `<pre>` tag (I thought this latter is used for formatted text).

Comment: @Kobra: Thank you for your comment. It does works. If you edit your answer to include the `<div>` solution, I would be pleased to accept it

Answer (score 27):

```
  pre {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Devalli - could you offer some explanation about why this works as well as just the code? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp "Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks"

Comment: seems like all I needed was `text-align: left`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use tags:

```
<pre><code>
Your text
Your text
</code></pre>
```

Remove all spaces preceding your text, all indentation.